# Python & PostgreSQL: Function to insert variable arg into table?

Tags: python, sql, database, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to do the code as follows to register a player with a given name, but I can't get the argument `name` to do anything… I thought that `%s` was the variable to insert a string into a database, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
import psycopg2

def registerPlayer(name):
    """Registers new player."""
    db = psycopg2.connect("dbname=tournament")
    c = db.cursor()
    c.execute("insert into Players values (%s);")
    db.commit()
    db.close()

registerPlayer("Butter")
```

When I run it, I get the error message:

```
ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "%"    
LINE 1: insert into Players values (%s);
```

Answer (score 3):

You haven't actually passed the parameter into the execute method.

```
c.execute("insert into Players values (%s);", (name,))
```

Comment: I knew I was missing something obvious. Thanks!